# Unselect item on load form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with Data Grid View:

[image]

So when my form loads, an item in the DataGridView is already selected. I want to know how I can unselect it. I tried with:

```
DataGridView1.ClearSelection();
```

But it just don't works, it only removes the blue background for the item but the item is still selected. What can I do? Regards

Comment: How do you know it is still selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle `Shown` event or override `OnShown` and set the `CurrentCell` of the `DataGridView` to null:

```
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnShown(e);
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
}
```